# check a condition before calling oncheckedchanged listener in android

Tags: android, radio-button

i have a radio group for whom i have implemented `onCheckedChanged` which is as follows:

```
RadioGroup mRadioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radio_grp);
mRadioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
```

My activity implements `OnCheckedChangeListener`,

```
@Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
        switch (group.getId()) {
        case R.id.radio_grp:
            if (my condition is true) {
                Log.d(TAG, "want to change the radio group's checked button if code reaches here.");
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "do not want to change the radio group's checked button if code reaches here.");
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
```

Now whenever user clicks radio button, it fires the code inside onCheckedChanged and also checked the radio button which is clicked by user. But i want to check if "my condition is true" then only it should change the radio button selection and do not change if condition is false.

can anyone suggest what should i do achieve this?

Thanks!

PS: I am also not able to think what should i write in the "Subject" of this question so if anyone can conclude the subject, please edit it.

PPS: I tried resetting the radio group's state via `group.check(R.id.last_selected_id);` but this will throw an StackoverFlow Exception as the code will stuck in a never ending loop.

Comment: What kind of condition do you have in your oncheckedchanged listener? Does this condition depend on the new selected radio button?

Comment: No.. i am implementing "in-app-billing" so i am checking whether user has the access to the feature controlled by radio button. If he has purchased it then condition will return true else false.

Comment: Maybe I did not understand your problem clearly because of my bad English I am sorry about it but why do not you use a public boolean variable to control this condition?

Comment: I am controlling the condition via a public boolean variable but the problem is that as soon as the code reaches in "onCheckedChanged" function, it first changes the checked button and then runs my code.

Comment: Ok now I completely understand the problem. Maybe you can disable clickListener of your radio button group if user does not meet your condition. Alternatively you can reselect previous selected radio button in the condition which you do not want to change selected radio button.

Comment: there is no explicit click listener for radio buttons, it is controlled by "oncheckedchanged". The code which i have provided in the question is the only code.